# jQuery how to check td value and compare it to array

Tags: jquery

I have an array

```
arr = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
```

and I want to check `td` value if it contains a value from my array. If yes, I would like to set a value of another `td`

I try this, but doesn't work:

```
   <table>
     <tr>
      <td class="woj">value1</td>
      <td class="user"></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td class="woj">value5</td>
      <td class="user"></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td class="woj">value6</td>
      <td class="user"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>

var arr = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];     
var woj = $('.woj').html();
if($.inArray(woj, arr) > -1) {         
    $(".user").text("user1");
 }
```

Comment: How does the newly inserted text relate to the values in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iteration over all `.woj` elements and in case inner text in the array, modify next table cell content:

```
var arr = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];     

$('.woj').each(function(i) {
    if (arr.indexOf($(this).text().trim()) > -1) {         
        $(this).next().text("user" + i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works fine. But when I add extra columns beetwen, like

Comment: Works fine. But when I add extra columns beetwen, like `<tr><td class="woj">value1</td><td>dd</td><td>ee</td><td class="usr"></td></tr>` I can't input the value into 'usr' cell. I tried `$(this).next('.usr').text("user" + i);` but it didn't work

Comment: Then it will be `$(this).nextAll('.usr').text("user" + i);`

Comment: maybe try using some framework, like knockout :) things will get easier, as you'll be operation in models, not DOM

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are many elements matching your selector '.woj'.

Try to iterate through all of them and check each of them separately. Also its better to use innerText property instead of the html method. More or less

```
$.each($('.woj'), function(idx, td){
    if($.inArray(td.innerText, arr) ....
});
```

In general, such thinga are easier if you introduce a framework, like knockout. Then you operate on data model, not on the presentation layer and parsing DOM.